# Which methods does PyCharm used to install requirements?

Tags: pycharm, conda

PyCharm can pop up an Install Requirements, and help install the packages.
I am wondering does PyCharm use Conda or Pip.
I am using a Conda environment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, PyCharm have to solve environment mechanism, which inspects your environment then install it accordingly.

Assume you are going to use `from django.http import HttpResponse` and PyCharm installs the package:

- conda: `conda install -c anaconda django`
- pip: `pip install Django`

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm knows which kind of environment you are using. When you select default project environment, you will see if it is a conda (with the green wheel) or just a normal virtual environment. Note: there are some files specific to conda, so it is easy to get the kind. PyCharm has sometime problems with Conda, if you install Conda in a non standard directory, but this happens in other tools, not to install packages.

I assume when PyCharm find a new module, it will look for conda package (if you are in a conda environment), and eventually fall back to pip. This last step is necessary, because pip has much more packages then conda (and pip in conda is also a modified version, to play well with conda).

I do not know if it is still true, but last year Conda and PyCharm (really the two companies) agreed to help each other to better integrate conda in PyCharm, so you should expect a good integration between the two tools.